# Moving text up towards <h1> in CSS

Tags: css, text

I am trying to move this paragraph header up towards my h1.  I don't really understand how to incorporate the position function. I have tried to use padding but it doesn't work.

ok so in the picture I am trying to get the " where every connections matters" right below the "Boblo"

The bottom is my HTML code

```
.jumbotron h1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:5px
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>BOBLO</h1>
  <p>Where every connection matters</p>
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide us more information (markup atleast) than that. Can you provide a fiddle example?

Comment: Yeah please provide current CSS & HTML for the `<header>` & `<h1>`. This helps us to understand you're question a hell of a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to h1 and remove the margin-bottom, please see and try the code below. You can take my implementation and adapt to suit your needs.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="test">TEST HEADING</h1>
<header>HEADER</header>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bootstrap (I guess), than you have to set `<h1>`tag the `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom` to zero.

```css
.jumbotron .container h1 {
   text-align: left;
   color: white;
   font-size: 60px;  
   font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-top:20px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
  
}
.jumbotron .container p {
   font-size: 30px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>BOBLO</h1>
      <p>Where every connection matters</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the gap between `<h1>` and `<p>` again to large you can fix this with `line-height`.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the margin and padding in `h1` is probably the cleanest solution. But sometimes that doesn't work, I then just always apply `position:relative; top:-20px;`. This moves the element 20px up from the position where it normally would have been:

```css
.jumbotron .container h1 {
   text-align: left;
   color: white;
   font-size: 60px;  
   font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-top:20px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
       
}
.jumbotron .container p {
   font-size: 30px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
   position:relative; 
   top:-20px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>BOBLO</h1>
      <p>Where every connection matters</p>
    </div>
</div>
```